# C# class dictionary data synchronization

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a quite strange issue with my program that I haven't seen ever and I can't really find why/how it is happening.

I have a class which holds dictionaries and a lot of variables, the issue I found is that when I run my program a class/dictionary doesn't get updated with data when the program is running sometimes, I get old data displayed, but when I put a breakpoint and watch the class I can't see the contents sometimes, so to debug I intentionally call a method that does nothing and when I am inside the class I can watch the dictionary and all the variables to see the contents, if I look into the dictionary there may be 100s of items, but the only items that are shown are the ones that I scroll with the mouse while debugging the contents, so if I can see 20 items only 20 items are displayed outside the class, if I watch 40 in total then 40 are displayed, if I scroll through the whole contents of the dictionary I can see all. Again when data source gets updated dictionary is not sync up and have to break and do the same operation to get everythig refreshed. It is driving me nuts because I can't figure out why is happening, any ideas?

By the way, the dictionary data gets updated in another thread, while the class is also updated in different thread.

Comment: Is there any chance that you could use some more full-stops? I'm impressed with the four that you used, but when it becomes easier to count the full-stops than read the question you probably need to do some editing. Adding code that shows what's going on would help immensely too.

Comment: have u handled the threading issue while updating the GUI? Please post the code with which you facing the problem..

Comment: It is quite complicated to post code since there are at least 6 classes with 4 threads running in other classes, so I will have to post a very long list of files.

Comment: I just actually managed to get the issue resolved but I don't know why is working now, I think it has to do with the threads, somehow in the thread that updates the dictionary I put a breakpoint and after I continued it started to work perfectly, so I can assume that is a threading synchronization issue. Anyone knows if a thread continues when the main program runs into a breakpoint?